# Do I need to sanitize my login value in php

Tags: php

Following is script I used in login page

```
<?php
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if ($user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

//process login form if submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }
}//end if submit
//define page title
$title = 'Login';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
?>
```

Do I need to sanitize these inputs with at least `mysql_real_escape_string` or can I use this code?

user.php

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){  

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }       
    }

}


?>
```

password_verify() code

```
public function password_verify($password, $hash) {
        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
        if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) != strlen($hash) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
            return false;
        }

        $status = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ret); $i++) {
            $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
        }

        return $status === 0;
    }

}
```

Since am new to PHP I am confused about it. Can someone help me?

or will user class will protect this login

Comment: Please, [do not use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard `PDO` i don;t know anything about it, and searched about it using prepared statement will help protect can you please make a example

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: Check the link in the comment I made. There is a tutorial there.

Comment: @copeg am using function

Comment: That depends completely on the `User` class you are using. In your code you are not doing any database operations, outputting to the screen, etc. so for what would you need to sanitize?

Comment: Sidenote: Sure hope you're storing a hash for this. **Edit:** and as per your edit; good.

Comment: @jeroen check my question add user class i used `pdo` is this secure

Comment: probably best suited for code review instead. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you've working code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- after edit will the above code is safe i use `user` class and `password` hash

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's best suited for code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please [vote to close because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286591/1310566). Voting to close because it belongs somewhere else can cause situations where the question is closed on two places. It is okay to redirect people to other sites, but don't vote to close with that reason.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg it's exactly where it belongs. *Do I need to sanitize my login value in php*

Comment: `am using function` function? Where is the User class defined? If using an API (like phpbb3 which this looks similar to), there may be accessory functions to sanitize the data

Comment: let them deal with it. question's off-topic in so many respects.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did not try to say that it didn't belong on CR. It is a bit unclear how well the code is working, but I am assuming it works. (Although one answer here on SO suggests that it doesn't, which would not make it a good CR candidate) I'm just against the "vote to close because it belongs at xyz". There are [several](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251568/213556) meta [posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289949/1310566) related to this.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I may have voted to close as such in a bit of a haste, however the OP doesn't mention whether their code works or not; therefore falling under different sections of Stack's "off-topic" choices. They should have tested their code before posting it and possibly making me look like a fool.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now that I totally agree with. At Code Review we often get "*Does* this code work? How can it be made better?" questions, while CR is more about "This works. How can it be made better?". The only way to know if your code works is really to test it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg +1 ^ Exactly. This probably won't be the last neither lol *cheers*

Answer (score 3):

Does this actually work?

I see:

```
if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
```

But there is no `password_verify()` method in your class. If you mean the `password_verify()` function, you should change it to:

```
if(password_verify($password,$hashed)){
```

To answer your question, you are using prepared statements so you should not escape your data, you are safe from sql injection. Even if you needed to - if you would inject a value directly into a query somewhere for example - you would need a PDO escaping function and not the `mysql_*` one. But using prepared statements consistently is obviously the better solution as you cannot forget anything by accident.

The only real problem that I can see is that you echo out your catched exception message to the user. You should log that instead and present the user with a non-technical error message.

And of course you should add error handling to the database calls: An empty result is not an error and will not lead to an exception, but it will lead to problems in your code, so you should check for that.

Comment: If you escape your data when using prepared statements, you can actually introduce errors into your data. Because the escaped string will be inserted literally. So `O'reilly` would be `O\'reilly` in your db; not what you want.

Comment: @dan08 Hmmmmm, perhaps my wording is not clear enough, I'll improve it.

Comment: I was just adding some clarification, you said "you don't *have* to" and I remember when I was learning, I thought I was being super safe by escaping and using prepared statements.

Comment: @dan08 I know and you are right, so I modified it :-)

Comment: Agreeing here. However, they really should have tested their code before posting their question. It falls into code review, unclear, why it's not working sections and maybe even another, far as I can see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I figured that if it really got moved, they'd move the answer with it so I might as well get it out of my system ;-)

Comment: @jeroen hehehe, true. Caffeine however, stays in your system too but not as long as the question will ;-)

Comment: @jeroen yes am using `password_verify()` in another file `include('password.php');` its located on `user.php` file and just add `password_verify()` to question